# java class cannot override size() from Component?

Tags: java, swing

Can we not override size() from the Component class in Java?

This is in a simple class, myPanels is an ArrayList  that has been initialized in the constructor.

```
    /**
 * Returns number of panels
 */
@Override
public int size(){
    return myPanels.size();
}
```

Error reads:
The return type is incompatible with Component.size()

---

---

**EDIT - SOLUTION**

Solution was to choose a different method name. Used something other than 'size()'

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find a way to reliably change the size of a GUI component, then you should override `getPreferredSize()` instead of dealing with size or `getSize()`. This way your components will play nice with most layout managers.

Else if you're using this method to return the size of an ArrayList that it holds and not to try to set the visualized size of a component, then give your class a method to do this, but don't name it `getSize()`  as that will confuse both other coders and the compiler. Instead name it `getMyPanelSize()` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks! Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're overriding java.awt.Component.size()

A: It's been deprecated since Java 1.1, use getSize() instead.

B: Either way, it must return a Dimension

Comment: Can I not add a method called size() in my class?

Comment: Not if you're extending Component and have the same method signature as Component.size(), I mean, of course you <em>can</em>, but the return type must be compatible.

Comment: My class extends JPanel, so I won't be able to do that I'm assuming.

Comment: Well, here's the thing: if you're overriding size (or getSize), I would assume you want the size of the Panel, if not, use a more specific method name == problem solved. This will disambiguate your code, so you don't wonder why size() doesn't return the size of the Panel later. (and this is also why Java won't let you reuse the name to do something else)

Answer (score 0):

The size() must return Dimension, and is deprecated since 1.1

I think you want to override the getSize() ?

> Before Java 5.0, when you override a method, both parameters and
>   return type must match exactly. In Java 5.0, it introduces a new
>   facility called covariant return type. You can override a method with
>   the same signature but returns a subclass of the object returned. In
>   another words, a method in a subclass can return an object whose type
>   is a subclass of the type returned by the method with the same
>   signature in the superclass.

Comment: Yes, but I thought you meight want to use the un-deprecated one and override it. But I see now in your case you want to return an int. Easy solution is to chose another name instead of size, something like getSizePanels() ?

Answer (score 0):

The `size()` method of Component returns an object of type `Dimension` - which means you can't return an int.

An approach is to just name the method something else, like `panelsSize()`. Another is to return a `Dimension`.